# If both application.yml and bootstrap.yml exist, who will overwrite whom with the same attributes?

Tags: spring-boot-2.6.0

I tried locally that the application will be covered, but when I checked online, many people said that the bootstrap would not be covered by the bootstrap, so I was very confused.

Is it because of different versions?

Answer (score 0):

In spring doc, there said:

> By default, bootstrap properties (not bootstrap.properties but properties that are loaded during the bootstrap phase) are added with high precedence, so they cannot be overridden by local configuration.

If you defined a non-bootstrap properties, it will override bootstrap.yml

Answer (score -1):

In fact, this problem is the priority of the `springboot` configuration file.

In `springboot`, the priority of `bootstrap` is higher than `application`, so if both parties have the same properties, `bootstrap` will be loaded first, then the `application` configuration will be loaded, and then the same properties of the former will be overwritten Lose.

The `springBoot` convention is greater than the configuration, the configuration follows from the inside to the outside, the outer layer covers the inner layer, and `bootstrap` is configured in the `spring applicationContext` stage, while `application` is configured in the application layer, so the external will Replace the inner layer.